# CGI won't run just download on Apache server

Tags: c, apache, cgi

I'm completly new to CGI and Apache but I'm trying out a few things. To start I wrote a simple hello CGI in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
    printf("<html>\n");
    printf("<head><title>CGI Output</title></head>\n");
    printf("<body>\n");
    printf("<h1>Hello, world.</h1>\n") ;
    printf("</body>\n");
    printf("</html>\n"); 
}
```

compiled it `gcc hello.c -o hello.cgi` and placed it in /var/www/mycgi

Afterward I modified httpd.conf to add the following

```
ScriptAlias /mycgi/ "/var/www/mycgi/"
```

in the IfModule alias_module and

```
<Directory "/var/www/mycgi">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have then restarted Apache and when I go to localhost/mycgi/hello.cgi the browser just downloads the file instead of running it. Help will be greatly apreciated!

Comment: Is the file executable? (`chmod +x hello.cgi`) Did you load the `cgi_module`? (`LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so`)

Answer (score 3):

According to [janos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641955/janos)'s advice, you should make sure apache2 has [loaded the cgi_module: LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/cgi.html). You can do this by:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/cgi.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/cgi.load
```

then restart apache2 and it will load the `cgi.load` file this time.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's an old question, I think many other guys will get the same problem...
First we must tell Apache what kind of files he must "exec" and where are theses files:

Edit *etc/apache2/apache2.conf* (using nano for example)

Add

```
<Directory "/home/johnny/public_html">
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
```

In this case Apache will try to exec all files ending with .cgi located in the public_html of user "johnny". You can add more than one extension for exemple:

*AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pif .gloup*

and so on.

To compile: cd to the folder where the .c source is and then:

*gcc hello.c*

This will give a file named "a" (or maybe a.out, it depend on the OS).
To change the name of the result:

*gcc hello.c -o ../public_html/my_cgi.gloup*

in case of .gloup has been added with AddHandler and of an exec file you want to access via the web.

In many cases, this will give an error. You can try to change the right, exec and so on, it's of no use.
The problem came from the fact in many cases, we run gcc as "root", so the result owner is root. And when we try to exec it from the web, we're not "root".

The solution is to change user. For exemple if your public_html folder owner is "johnny", when you are logged as root, just do:

*su - johnny*

and now you "are" johnny. Just cd to the folder wih your c fles, compile using gcc and you'll be able to exec from the web.