# when trying to run cgi it downloads instead

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, cgi

EDIT: Following answers to similar questions I had claimed ownership of the folder and files with `chown`. Once I set the permissions to the folder to 777 it start working.

I don't know much about Apache configuration, but so far I've been able to get it to play along with my web applications.
Now I was trying to learn some stuff in C, and here's what's happening:

1. when I open the files from my browser on `http://localhost/cgi-bin/` it all works just fine; - files being in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/`
2. when I move the files to `/var/www/cgi-bin/` and try to open them on the browser from `http://codigoc/` all it does is downloading the files instead of running them.

I've been searching online, but haven't found a solution yet.
As I'm not sure exactly what needs to be done, I'll leave you my files below.

/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfDefine ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </IfDefine>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/cgi-bin/>
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
</Directory>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/codigoc.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName codigoc

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cgi-bin/
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/cgi-bin

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -Multiviews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>                            
   
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Not sure if this is enough for you guys to help me, but if I'm missing something please let me know.

Comment: Worth checking whether your script file attributes are set as executable.

Comment: @John Sheridan: it is

Comment: I can run them on the browser when I put them on /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ and opent them through http://localhost/cgi-bin/ works perfectly fine that way, but I want them on the /var/www/cgi-bin/ dir and that's where I'm getting issue

Comment: Just looking through the apache docs (been a very long time since I configured apache) and I see that DocumentRoot should be specified without a trailing slash.  Your conf file has DocumentRoot /var/www/cgi-bin/.

Comment: @John Sheridan; thank you for the correction, already changed that. The problem is still there tho

Comment: Just read your question again.  You are working in C.  I had assumed that your "script" extensions had either .cgi or .pl, but if you are working in C that is probably not the case.  You have an entry in your apache2.conf ... AddHandler where you explicitly list .cgi and .pl.  I'm wondering whether you should have just used SetHandler cgi-script so that it will treat all files  in cgi-bin as executable.

Comment: @John Sheridan: tried changing it, what happens is the following: I stop getting access on the browser to the dir on http:// codigoc/ and when it specify one of the files (ie: http:// codigoc/logic2) it downloads it as before

Comment: Another thing to check ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335987/cgi-wont-run-just-download-on-apache-server

Comment: a2enmod cgi says its already loaded and the file (cgi.load) is there on mods-enabled with the following: LoadModule cgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cgi.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a permissions issue... its solved now

Thanks John, and sorry for taking up your time

EDIT: Following answers to similar questions I had claimed ownership of the folderand files with chown. Once I set the permissions to the folder to 777 it start working.

Comment: Great.  You're sorted.  Change the permissions to 755 though rather than 777.